# Is for loop necessary to read data from tcp connection in go?

Tags: for-loop, go, tcp

There's a func to handle tcp connection:

```
for {
    select {
    case conn := <-listen:
        go handleClient(conn)
    ...
}

func handleClient(client net.Conn) {
    for {
       // ...read from conn
       // at some point return
       return
    }
}
```

My question is , if you use `for` loop, you must write `return` or it will be a  dead loop. If it returns, this `handleClient` function will execute only once. So `for` is not necessary here, right? We can still read all of the data Without `for` , is this the right way to think ?

Answer (score 1):

A common pattern for a server handling connections might be

```
func handleClient(conn net.Conn) {
    r := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    for {
        line, err := r.ReadBytes(byte('\n'))
        switch err {
        case nil:
            break
        case io.EOF:
        default:
            fmt.Println("ERROR", err)
        }
        // do something with the data, in this case echo it back
        conn.Write(line)
    }
}
```

The for {} loop is necessary to read multiple lines of data from the connection.

If the handleClient can read the input all in one chunk then a loop isn't necessary

So, yes you are right the for {} is not always necessary but it depends what data is being read.  Often a loop like this is the best way to read the data

Comment: you need to return in the `default:` condition